# Partial derivative of sums with different index's

Tags: calculus

I have a problem which I'm trying to solve. The problem is as follows:

$$z=\sum_i \sum_j (x_i*k_{i,j}*H_{i,j})
$$

where I'm trying to find $\partial z/\partial x$. Any tips on how I can plug this into wolfram?

Comment: The notation might not be the best

Answer (score 0):

The $x_i$ term does not belong to the inner summation; so $$z=\sum_i \sum_j x_i\,k_{ij}\,H_{ij}=\sum_i x_i\sum_j k_{ij}\,H_{ij}=\sum_i \alpha_i\,x_i$$ where $$\alpha_i=\sum_j k_{ij}\,H_{ij}$$ So, $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_k}=\alpha_k$$

Comment: You are very welcome !

Comment: any chance you can aid in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326093/partial-derivative-of-a-sum-with-several-subscripts ?