# Partial derivative of a sum with several subscripts

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am struggling to find the first derivative of a summation with two subscripts. The solution might be simple, but I'm struggling to get the idea. Any hint or help is appreciated.

I have the following equation;

$$z=\sum_i \sum_j x_{i,j}*k_{i}*H_{i}
$$

Where I want to find the derivative w.r.t x. It feels like I'm missing some basic concept, I can't even, in a clean way, figure out the derivative of: 
$$z=\sum_{i,j}(x_{i,j})
$$
w.r.t x.

I've read Concrete mathematics and tried other sources, but I can't find any clear information. Any tip on the way?